# Sort by two columns with dataTables (Cannot read property 'sType' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using [dataTables plugin](http://datatables.net) to deal with the sorting of columns.

Trying to apply the [multi-column ordering](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html) I'm getting the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sType' of undefined

As the documentation is not very explanatory in this regard and doesn't contain too many examples for this feature, I don't know where the problem is.

[Reproduction of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/L5gbck06/)

```
$('#demo').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    ordering: true,
    columnDefs: [{
        orderData: [[0, 'asc'],[1, 'asc']],
        targets: [1]
    }]
});
```

Comment: In reference to your original console error and bug report: your code is valid, but you need to remove the `targets` parameter in order for that syntax to work - the target columns are already specified in the `orderdata` array. See http://jsfiddle.net/4edtajv3/ with the multi-column ordering working.

Comment: @E.Serrano that's not the same. That's a single column ordering and not a multi column.

Comment: True. And multi-column order still works when shift-clicking the column titles.

Comment: @E.Serrano but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: But that fixes the Uncaught TypeError, correct? Now, for multi-ordering: `orderFixed` enforces that the ordering criteria of the chosen column will always be in effect http://jsfiddle.net/yfaac1z2/2/ - though the order indicating arrow changes on click, and it shouldn't because `orderable` sets it to ignore user input.

Comment: My bad: I had a wrong "orderable" syntax. This does all you want your table to do now http://jsfiddle.net/zL1y8rv3/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CAUSE**

Option [columns.orderData](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData) should be array of indexes, see below:

```
$('#demo').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    ordering: true,
    columnDefs: [{
        orderData: [0, 1],
        targets: [1]
    }]
});
```

See [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5gbck06/1/) for demonstration.

Although [Multi-column ordering](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html) example page mentions that you can use `[ [0,'asc'], [1,'asc'] ]`, however it contradicts with the manual for [columns.orderData](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData).

Seems like an issue either with code or the manual. By looking at the DataTables source code I see that it only accepts array of indexes without sorting method.

**DETAILS**

Created a [new issue #591](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/591) for jQuery DataTables regarding this issue.

It is now [confirmed](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/591#issuecomment-118908879) that the issue was with incorrect statement on [Multi-column ordering](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html) example page.

**WORKAROUND**

The workaround is to bind to [order](http://datatables.net/reference/event/order) event and re-order the table as you want with [order()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/order%28%29) method that accepts sorting method in addition to column index.

```
var table = $('#demo').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    ordering: true
});

$('#demo').on('order.dt', function(){
   var order = table.order();              
   if(order[0][0] === 1){
      table.order([0, 'asc'],[1, 'asc']).draw();
   }
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5gbck06/3/) for demonstration.

Comment: From [the docs](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html): "Using the columns.orderDataDT option to specify a multiple column order by default (for example [ [0,'asc'], [1,'asc'] ])."

Comment: How do you specify the direction of the sorting then. I want to sort in ascending by the 1st column, then by whatever the user decides in any other column.

Comment: What docs are you looking at? I don't see that syntax shown as an example [here](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData)

Comment: @BLSully just the link I posted in my question. I updated my answer with the link to the official documentation as well where you can find it.

Comment: That's actually for the `order` parameter - [see here](http://datatables.net/reference/option/order)

Comment: Seems like an issue with the documentation. I'm going to open a ticket and will post a link here for reference.

Comment: So... I guess there is no way to sort by two columns specifying the order?

Comment: Yes, the `order` parameter allows you to do that. See my updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d7dpmjj8/

Comment: There is a way to sort two columns specifying the order, it's not with `orderData` though.

Comment: @E.Serrano, `order` is for initial sort only.

Comment: @E.Serrano that's only for initial data.

Comment: I guess the answer is NO. Gonna look for other plugins.

Comment: @Alvaro, Can't post a solution yet, but I think the workaround is to bind to [order](http://datatables.net/reference/event/order) event and re-order the table as you want with [order()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/order%28%29) method that accepts sorting method in addition to index.

Comment: Alternatively, you can hold the `Shift` key while clicking on columns to order however you want. I see the point of the `orderData` parameter, but seems like a really narrow use case to throw out the whole plugin. It's really quite good minus that bug (which looks pretty easy to fix glancing at the line that's throwing the exception)

Comment: @BLSully, you are correct about `Shift` key but the point here is to be able to do that programmatically through API.

Comment: All you found is correct, sir. The topic evolved and I thought this was addressing a different issue. How can I change my vote? It seems the original needs to be edited to allow me re-casting my vote.

Comment: Fixed! Sorry about that.

Comment: @E.Serrano, thanks for the comment, I added a proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that multi-column order can work in dataTables, with:

- Multi-ordering enabled by default
- A first column with fixed ascending ording that ignores user input
- A second column where the user can choose sorting direction
- No need to shift-click to keep multi-ordering engaged

This sums up all the process:

```
    $('#demo').DataTable({
    ordering: true,         
    order:[[0, 'asc'],[1, 'asc']], // Set initial order
    orderFixed: [ 0, 'asc' ], // Always use the first column for ordering
    "columnDefs": [
    { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 } // Don't let the first column order to be changed
      ]
    });
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zL1y8rv3/1/).

Comment: Although your code works, I believe this is not what OP wanted. Also, if you downvote other answers, it's a good practice to leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: Yes, the OP asked for "How do you specify the direction of the sorting then. I want to sort in ascending by the 1st column, then by whatever the user decides in any other column" and "I guess there is no way to sort by two columns specifying the order?" - `orderFixed` seems to be a good workaround for that. Sorry about my misunderstanding on your relevant answer as the topic drifted.

Comment: Your code offers an alternative solution so I'm voting up. However there might be groups of columns that need to be sorted together which would be impossible with your code. Also your code prevents from sorting the first column individually.